# Implicit differentiation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Differentiate given

$$\frac{y}{x-y}=x^2+1$$

Initially I wanted to use the quotient rule to solve this, but then I tried differentiating it as it is:

$$\frac {y_\frac{dy}{dx}}{1-y_\frac{dy}{dx}}=2x$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(y y^{-1})=2x$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{yy^{-1}}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$$

I am wondering how I can check to see if this is a valid answer?

Comment: What is $y_{dy/dx}$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Quite possibly an error on my part. I arrived at $y_\frac{dy}{dx}$ by applying the chain rule to y. If I understand correctly, y is considered to be a function of x, so we apply the chain rule to y (when using implicit differentiation).

Comment: Explain to me what you mean by "$y_{dx/dy}$". In general, what do you mean by $f_g$, when $f$ and $g$ are functions?

Comment: I meant to express that y is a function of x. My aim was to differentiate the top of bottom of the rational expression. Since the expression is a relation versus a function, I thought I had to differentiate y using the chain rule.

Comment: Careful. The top is $y(x)$. The chain rule is used for compositions, and I see none (Do you?). What you ought to be doing is using the quotient rule and treating $y$ as $y(x)$ implicitly. I still can't understand why would you say a function is a functions of its derivative (when the converse might make more sense) or how you arrived to the expression $y'(y y^{-1})$. If you write out your reasoning it might help.

Comment: My confusion is over the concept of y being treated as y(x), implicitly. Clearly, I don't see why y is treated this way. If I was to differentiate the same expression for x, then I would assume  that x would be treated as x(y). That being said, I think that what was missing initially is that the relation between the two variables implies that one is a function of the other, depending on which one you are differentiating for. Additionally, my approach attempted to solve the rational side of the expression with out using the quotient rule. Thanks for your solution, it has cleared up my thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is

$$\frac{y}{x-y}=x^2+1 $$

You claim that

$$y'=2x$$ so that

$y=x^2+C$

This means

$$\frac{x^2+C}{x-x^2-C}=x^2+1 $$

This is absurd, since the quotient of two second degree polynomials can't be a second degree polynomial. In fact you get two non vanishing terms $x^3$ and $x^4$ which are off.

I don't understand what your procedure is, also. I would proceed as follows:

$$\displaylines{
  \frac{y}{{x - y}} = {x^2} + 1 \cr 
  \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{y}{{x - y}}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right) \cr 
  \frac{{y'\left( {x - y} \right) - \left( {1 - y'} \right)y}}{{{{\left( {x - y} \right)}^2}}} = 2x \cr 
  \frac{{y'x - yy' - y + yy'}}{{{{\left( {x - y} \right)}^2}}} = 2x \cr 
  \frac{{y'x - y}}{{{{\left( {x - y} \right)}^2}}} = 2x \cr 
  y'x = 2x{\left( {x - y} \right)^2} + y \cr 
  y' = 2{\left( {x - y} \right)^2} + \frac{y}{x} \cr} $$

Answer (score 2):

An explicit approach:

Rewrite as $y = (x-y)(x^2+1)$, and factor out $y$ to get $y = \frac{x^3+x}{x^2+2}$. This is straightforward to differentiate, yielding $\frac{d y}{d x} = \frac{x^4+5 x^2+2}{(x^2+2)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your final expression to get $y=x^2+c$ and see if this works in the original equation.